# How can I change H1 color as you scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page with a large 100% width photo at the top and a title on top of the photo. I would like to have the fixed position title change color as you scroll past the photo. I have been able to create a working version in jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtZDZ/647/

Here is the javascript (I am new to JS)

```
    var tStart = 100 // Start transition 100px from top
,
tEnd = 300 // End at 300px
,
cStart = [255, 255, 255] // white
,
cEnd = [156, 156, 156] // black
,
cDiff = [cEnd[0] - cStart[0], cEnd[1] - cStart[1], cEnd[1] - cStart[0]];

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var p = ($(this).scrollTop() - tStart) / (tEnd - tStart); // % of transition
    p = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, p)); // Clamp to [0, 1]
    var cBg = [Math.round(cStart[0] + cDiff[0] * p), Math.round(cStart[1] + cDiff[1] * p), Math.round(cStart[2] + cDiff[2] * p)];
    $("h1 a").css('color', 'rgb(' + cBg.join(',') + ')');
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, once I start scrolling the h1 no longer changes color when I hover over it. Also when I try to open a page with this code inside chrome the text simply goes from white to black instead of the dark grey as I specified. Does anyone know how to fix either of these issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the hover not working, the inline style that you are setting overrides the :hover state in your CSS.

Quick Fix:

```
h1 a:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200)!important;
}
```

Also, the link doesn't work in jsFiddle by design because it is running in an iframe. If you are really tempted to do this for some reason though, then add target="_parent" to the anchor tag

Comment: That quick fix worked great thank you. I don't suppose you know why this code wouldn't be working when I open it in chrome?

Comment: It looks like it is changing in chrome, it just does so very quickly. 

At 100px it becomes rgb(255,255,255).
At 200px it becomes rgb(206,206,206).
At 300px it becomes rgb(156,156,156).

Try making tEnd = 700. The color transform will be much smoother and not be so quick.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the color explicitly I would instead use class switching:

```
var title = $('h1:first'),
  titleText = title.find('a'),
  titleTextHeight = titleText.height(),
  meow = $('#meowmeow'),
  meowBottom = meow.offset().top + meow.outerHeight();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() + titleTextHeight > meowBottom) {
          titleText.addClass('bare');
        } else {
          titleText.removeClass('bare');
        }
    });
});
```

Then it is just a matter of selectors:

```
h1 a {
    position:fixed;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5%;
    font-size: 2em;
}
h1 a.bare {
    color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
}
h1 a:hover, h1 a.bare:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9PJ9g/1/

Comment: this looks good thank you. Is there a way to make the color change gradual as I had it before with this method? Also I noticed when I change the browser size the point of change is not always at the base of the div. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @patrick.altair It could be more gradual by having intermediate classes instead of just two, you could also use CSS animations to fade between them to make it a little smoother, but it wouldn't be a one for one fade like your original version. BTW, your original example doesn't work quite the way you want it to, you hard-coded the height of the image but the image re-sizes with the browser; you might want to use calculations similar to the ones in my answer to fix that, or an image that doesn't re-size.